# Pepper Robot Choreographe cannot stop running

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I've just starting working with Pepper on choreographe. The problem I'm having is when I play the behavior, choreographe doesn't stop running after the behavior is done, and the stop button doesn't work. In fact, I just run a really simple behavior with one Say box. So I'd have to disconnect and reconnect the robot whenever I want to play the behavior again. However, this issue doesn't occur when I connect to a virtual robot. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?
Choreographe: 2.5.10.7
Naoqi 2.5
OS: Ubuntu 14[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGqB.png)

Comment: Sometimes it can be related to the firewall options you grant to choregraphe: if it doesn't have enough, it won't receive signal back from Pepper.

Comment: @AlexandreMazel I am so delighted for your reply, but I still donot know how to fix it?  where I can setup firewall options? Could you tell me how to check? I think still has many new people come across this issue. One more informaiton I have to say is I installed a Virtual Box and install Ubuntu 14 and Choregraphe. my laptop I used Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: There should be some options in VirtualBox to remap port or decide which port are send to the virtual machine. See "port forwarding".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual machine is not set up to open listening ports exposed to your local area network. [This tutorial](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-network-sharing.html) shows how to configure the network in general. You can select the option "Bridged adapter" to allow the virtual machine to do everything your host machine can with the network interface.

Comment: thank you, I fix it. I removed the old VM, and add a new one, and setup "Bridged adapter" and install Choreographe, it works. so the tip is try to do everything again, do not update on the current VM.